# React - BackgroundImage with data doesn't display

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm using React and i'm trying to inject dynamically a backgroundImage from a data.json, so i'm writing my backgroundImage directly in the jsx, as inline-style, but the background don't wants to show up. I've already checked the source, and it's correct !

I'll give you a code sample and a screen of my console to show you that my path for the backgroundImage is correct !

```
const Card = ({ artCard }) => {
const backgroundThumbnail = artCard.images.thumbnail;
console.log(backgroundThumbnail);
return (
<React.Fragment>
  <div
    className="card"
    style={{
      backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundThumbnail})`,
      backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
      backgroundSize: "cover",
      backgroundPosition: "center",
      minHeight: "300px",
      minWidth: "300px",
    }}
  >
    {/* <h3>{artCard.name}</h3> */}
    {/* <h4>{artCard.artist.name}</h4> */}
  </div>
</React.Fragment>
);
};
```

Screenshot 
[image: google console]

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add a double quote inside the bracket, try this:

```
backgroundImage: `url("${backgroundThumbnail}")`
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: It doesn't work ! Maybe i could try background, without url ?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, found the problem, my images were not on the public folder, so react won't read it !